# Mysql Procedure IF,ELSEIF Statment error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to create a procedure in mysql, but i get an syntax error, i don`t know why i get it and where is ''

`# 1064 - You have an error in the RSQL syntax next to '' on line 4`

My Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MUWAP_VipAdd(IN szCharName varchar(10),IN DayAdd int,IN VipType smallint,IN datenow_srv datetime)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `T_VIPList` WHERE AccountID = szCharName) THEN
INSERT INTO `T_VIPList` (`AccountID`,`Date`,`Type`) VALUES (szCharName,DATE_ADD(datenow_srv, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),VipType);
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `T_VIPList`  WHERE AccountID = szCharName AND Date > datenow_srv) THEN
UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Date` = DATE_ADD(`Date`,INTERVAL DayAdd DAY) WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName;
UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Type` = VipType WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName AND `Type` < VipType;
ELSE 
UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Date` = DATE_ADD(`Date`,INTERVAL DayAdd DAY), `Type` = VipType WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName;
END IF
END
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have multiple statements in a `THEN` statement, you need to use `BEGIN...END`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MUWAP_VipAdd(IN szCharName varchar(10),IN DayAdd int,IN VipType smallint,IN datenow_srv datetime)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `T_VIPList` WHERE AccountID = szCharName) 
    THEN INSERT INTO `T_VIPList` (`AccountID`,`Date`,`Type`) VALUES (szCharName,DATE_ADD(datenow_srv, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),VipType);
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `T_VIPList`  WHERE AccountID = szCharName AND Date > datenow_srv) 
    THEN BEGIN
        UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Date` = DATE_ADD(`Date`,INTERVAL DayAdd DAY) WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName;
        UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Type` = VipType WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName AND `Type` < VipType;
    END
    ELSE UPDATE `T_VIPList` SET `Date` = DATE_ADD(`Date`,INTERVAL DayAdd DAY), `Type` = VipType WHERE `AccountID` = szCharName;
    END IF
END
```

You could also combine the two `UPDATE` queries into a single query:

```
UPDATE T_VIPList
SET Date = DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),
    Type = GREATEST(VipType, Type)
WHERE AccountID = szCharName;
```

In fact, it seems like the whole thing could be done with a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query:

```
INSERT INTO T_VIPList (AccountID, Date, Type)
VALUES (szCharName,DATE_ADD(datenow_srv, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),VipType)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Date = IF(Date > datenow_srv, VALUES(Date), Date),
    Type = GREATEST(Type, VALUES(Type));
```

Comment: Same error  `# 1064 - You have an error in the RSQL syntax next to '' on line 4`

Comment: If i delete `;` from line 4, i get `# 1064 - You have an error in the RSQL syntax next to 'ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 'T_VIPList'  WHERE AccountID = szCharName AND Date' on line 5`

Comment: Is that the exact error message? I've never heard of "RSQL". Are you using MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: When I search for RSQL, I find a Ruby gem for SQL: https://github.com/bradrf/rsql

Comment: Very interesting all in single insert, but i get same error:

`# 1064 - You have an error in the RSQL syntax next to 'Type = GREATEST (Type, VALUES (`Type`))' on line 7`

`CREATE PROCEDURE MUWAP_VipAdd(IN szCharName varchar(10),IN DayAdd int,IN VipType smallint,IN datenow_srv datetime)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_VIPList (AccountID, Date, Type)
VALUES (szCharName,DATE_ADD(datenow_srv, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),VipType)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Date = IF(Date > datenow_srv, VALUES(Date), Date)
    Type = GREATEST(Type, VALUES(Type));
END`

Comment: I use MariaDB, i forget to add tag

Comment: That doesn't look like the way MariaDB reports its errors, either. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/parentheses/ for an example error from MariaDB.

Comment: I was missing a comma at the end of the `Date =` line.

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.32-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: # 1064 - You have an error in the RSQL syntax next to '' on line 7 (with comma)

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. And I still don't understand why it says RSQL syntax instead of SQL syntax.

Comment: It works like this: `CREATE PROCEDURE MUWAP_VipAdd( IN szCharName varchar(10),IN DayAdd int,IN VipType smallint,IN datenow_srv datetime) INSERT INTO T_VIPList (AccountID, Date, Type)
VALUES (szCharName,DATE_ADD(datenow_srv, INTERVAL DayAdd DAY),VipType)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Date = IF(Date > datenow_srv, VALUES(Date), Date),
    Type = GREATEST(Type, VALUES(Type))`

Without BEGIN - END.... very strange

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I lost 3 hours with this error